# OPENXML of T-SQL does not work with root node with meta data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to read XML document. Root node of XML has some meta data because of the I am not getting any records. If i remove that meta data it works fine. is there any way to ignore that meta data and still retrieve the data from XML.

```
DECLARE @myDoc XML,
        @idoc INT;
SET @myDoc
    = '<Leads xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/RACLeadXMLSchema.xsd">
  <LeadElement>
    <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
    <LastName>pqr</LastName>
    <Email>abc@gmail.com</Email>
    <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
    </LeadElement>
</Leads>';

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @myDoc;

SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       Email,
       PhoneNumber
FROM
    OPENXML(@idoc, 'Leads/LeadElement')
    WITH
    (
        FirstName VARCHAR(100) 'FirstName',
        LastName VARCHAR(100) 'LastName',
        Email VARCHAR(100) 'Email',
        PhoneNumber VARCHAR(100) 'PhoneNumber'
    );
```

Comment: Jay, `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used anymore. Much better are the native XML-type methods. The duplicate answer shows an example how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with last namespace declaration in Leads element.

```
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/RACLeadXMLSchema.xsd"
```

you should have some variable after `xmlns`. Try something like below.

`xmlns:xsk="http://tempuri.org/RACLeadXMLSchema.xsd"`

Comment: I can not edit the XML. Can we do something else?